# Angular 5 basic search components

Tags: angular, search, angular5

I have a search component. This has a template that is basically just an input field and a button. On submit I require it to load data from my API. This data needs to be displayed in my search results component.

My search component looks like this:

```
search(f) {
  this.router.navigate(['/item/search/' + f.value.itemSearch]);
}
```

This route renders the search results component. The benefit of doing this is that a user can manually alter the URL to search for what they want /item/search/whatever.

Code in search-results component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.route.params
  .switchMap(params => {
    this.postcode = params['item'] || '';
    return this.service.search(this.item);
  })
  .subscribe(
    items => this.items = items
  );
```

}

The problem I have is whenever a search is done and it returns a 404/400 whatever, it correctly shows no data was found. However subsequent searches using the search component do nothing. I can reenter the data and re-hit submit and the URL changes, but the search isn't performed again. Any ideas?

Hope that all makes sense :-/

Addition:

```
search(item: string): Observable<any> {
  const search = new URLSearchParams();
  search.set('item', item);
  return this.http.get(this._apiUrl, { search })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: can you show the part of the code where you fetch your data from the server? this seems not to be part of what you have shown so far.

Comment: Added to the bottom. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your handleError method doesn't actually handle the error, but propagates it, when doing

```
this.subscription = this.route.params
  .switchMap(params => {
    this.postcode = params['item'] || '';
    return this.service.search(this.item);
  })
  .subscribe(
    items => this.items = items
  );
```

if an error is emitted by the search observable, then the whole observable pipeline is stopped, and stuck in its terminal error state. So, whatever the params observable emits doesn't matter: events won't be received anymore.

You need to actually hande the error, by returning a non-error observable. Something like

```
this.subscription = this.route.params
  .switchMap(params => {
    this.postcode = params['item'] || '';
    return this.service.search(this.item).catch(() -> {
      // display no result somehow
      return Observable.empty());
    });
  })
  .subscribe(
    items => this.items = items
  );
```